# OpenMP: possible different condition in a for-loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize a for-loop using OpenMP (I've done it myself using std::threads before, but that solution was rather ugly), however it's condition may change on each iteration.
Here is the example of what I mean:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < someVector.size(); i++)
{
. . .
if(something)
   someVector.push_back(v);
}
```

However, that doesn't work. The loop seems to go as far as the initial someVector.size() value. Is there a way to parallelize such a construction in OpenMP?

Comment: Is `something` dependent on `i`?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then it seems unlikely that you'll be able to parallelize it, if it uses global data.

Answer (score 3):

This code is non-conforming: the for statement doesn't have the canonical form required by the spec to be a loop that can be annotated with a `#pragma omp parallel for` (section 2.6 of the [OpenMP 4.5 spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf)).

The problem is in the conditional expression: the spec states that if your conditional expression has the form `i relational-op expr`, `expr` has to be a loop invariant expression, and this constraint is not fulfilled by your code.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenMP `#pragma omp for` understands the condition in the for loop. It knows that it iterates over numbers from 0 to some maximum, so it evaluates the maximum at the beginning and then divides the work to several threads. If the maximum changes during the loop execution, it doesn't have effect.

Furthermore modifying `std::vector` while some other threads are using it is definitely not safe operation. You would get undefined behavior, probably crash because of accessing freed memory after the vector moved the stored data when growing.

You can replace the `std::vector` with some thread-safe queue. Then you can freely pop and push values in using multiple workers in parallel.